# Access specific appsettings key in Url Rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, web.config-transform

I am trying to access AppSettings Key in the Url Rewrite rules and I am not sure how to access them. Can anyone help me out?

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="APIUrl" value="https://www.x.com/api/{R:1}" />
</appSettings>
<system.webServer>  
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="ProxyApi" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^api/?(.*)" />
      <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
      </serverVariables>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{APIUrl}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
 </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Trying to access the APIUrl key in the UrlRewrite Rule

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am on the same situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that appsettings are unavailable elsewhere in your config files.

I've found two ways to address this issue using msbuild:

- Use [xmlupdate](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Documentation/TaskDocs.md#XmlUpdate) task from [MSBuild Community Tasks Project](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) to update config files. My work was using this already so it was the path that I took. Would look Like:

  ```
  <XmlUpdate 
    XPath="//rule[@name='ProxyApi']/action/@url"
    XmlFileName="{Your Config File Location}"
    Value="https://www.x.com/api/{R:1}" />
  ```
- Use [XslTransformation Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598688.aspx) to update your config files. This solution is built in but requires more knowledge of XSL. The Xsl would looke something like:

  ```
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//rule[@name='ProxyApi']/action/@url">
      <xsl:attribute name="url">
        <xsl:value-of select="'https://www.x.com/api/{R:1}'"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
  ```